# MySQL CREATE TABLE script and the table name

Tags: mysql

I'm playing with MySQL (curiosity, self-learning) and I've noticed a strange thing:

I want to create a table:

```
use `a`;

CREATE TABLE `Languages` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LanguageName` char(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but as the result, the table name is `languages` instead of `Languages`. Why ? Should I know something before create a table ?

Comment: Yes, you should: Table names are generally not case sensitive in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of your **lower_case_table_names** system variable.  If this variable has a value of 1, then MySQL converts all table names to lowercase for storage.  More information on this behavior can be found here: [MySQL Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

MySQL actually recommends this behavior as a way to avoid data transfer issues (from the doc linked above):

> To avoid data transfer problems arising from lettercase of database or
>   table names, you have two options:
>
> Use lower_case_table_names=1 on all systems. The main disadvantage
>   with this is that when you use SHOW TABLES or SHOW DATABASES, you do
>   not see the names in their original lettercase.
>
> Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and lower_case_table_names=2 on
>   Windows. This preserves the lettercase of database and table names.
>   The disadvantage of this is that you must ensure that your statements
>   always refer to your database and table names with the correct
>   lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your statements to Unix, where
>   lettercase is significant, they do not work if the lettercase is
>   incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is case insensitive in general (keywords and names), so upper/lower cases should not matter. Since mysql maps tables to files (MyISAM tables at least) it makes difference wether you using a Linux or Windows system. Imho you should not create names, where case matters.